# Resize image in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, html, eclipse

I have an array that fetches an image from the database and shows it.

However, the image size is too large. I have tried using `height='5' width='5'` but the image size does not change.

How do I adjust the size of my image?

My array

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     $("#mycase").append("Description: " + arr[0].CaseDes
                + "<br>" + "<tr><td><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" 
                + arr[0].Case_Pic  + "' height='5' width='5' >"
                + "<br>Category: " + arr[0].categoryname
                + "</td></tr>"); 
     GetAddress();
    }
```

Image for reference

[image: Image 1 for reference][image: Image 2 for reference]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your tryout. Maybe the bug is elsewhere?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions could it be due to my css folder?

Comment: Maybe look for css `img` rules, that have `important!` at a rule. Like `img {width:5px important!}`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions You were right, it was the img rules. I managed to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: ..  Nice ;-) ..            !